# How draw Bezier path with tikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bezier

How draw Bezier path like this with tikz?
[image: Bezier patch]

This patch is x(1-x-y)

I saw similar : https://tikz.net/torus/
How to use \addplot3 ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You'd want the `pgfplots` package (that is used in the example you linked to) but you will need a formula for the graph.

Comment: More accurate sample is https://tikz.net/saddle/    \begin{axis}[
      axis equal image,
      axis lines=middle,
      xmax=1,zmax=1,
      ticks=none,
      clip bounding box=upper bound,
      colormap/blackwhite
    ]
     \addplot3[surf,color=blue,opacity=0.5,domain=-1:1,z buffer=sort] {x*(1-x-y)};
  \end{axis}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! So, is the last comment of yours kind of your answer? What exactly is your question now since the above code seems already to go in the right direction.

Comment: @Saku as J Habicht said, what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Functions *x* (1 − *x* − *y*) and *y* (1 − *x* − *y*) are not too attractive for static image. Better are, for example, (*x* + *y*) (1 − *x* − *y*) and especially *x y* (1 − *x* − *y*).

Simple exmaple using `\addplot3`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[colormap/blackwhite]
     \addplot3[surf,color=blue,opacity=0.5,domain=-1:1,z buffer=sort] {x*y*(1-x-y)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]